# Handling a click over a balloon tip displayed with TrayIcon's ShowBalloonTip()

Tags: c#, .net, windows, vb.net

I use the `ShowBalloonTip` method of a `TrayIcon` class to display a balloon tip. Is there a way to handle a click over this balloon?

When I click over the balloon, no event seem to be generated, and it only closes the balloon.

Comment: When you say "click over" the balloontip do you mean *on* the balloontip or over it as in some other part of the desktop other than the balloontip?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I think you mean [NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984200%28VS.71%29.aspx) . Use following pattern...

```
NotifyIcon notifyIcon = null;
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
    // Initializing notifyIcon here...
    notifyIcon.BalloonTipClicked += new EventHandler(notifyIcon_BalloonTipClicked);
}

void notifyIcon_BalloonTipClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Operation you want...
}
```

I hope it feed your needs...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the following snippet? I managed to find it whilst doing a quick google search:

```
private void TrayNotifyIcon_BalloonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Perform Action
}
```

Obviously you'll need to make sure you specify the correct name in the method signature for your own application.

I think this was written in an older version of the .Net Framework and there's probably a newly named method for it.

Source: [Build a C# Notification System](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20060215.asp)