# How to add an action event to TrayIcon.displayMessage()

Tags: java, awt

Is it possible to add action event handling to the displayed message that shows up when calling `TrayIcon.displayMessage()` (the balloon message)? If so, how?

Comment: Probably a way right? What have you tried so far? any first-attempts at coding ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling a click over a balloon tip displayed with TrayIcon's ShowBalloonTip()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181594/handling-a-click-over-a-balloon-tip-displayed-with-trayicons-showballoontip)

Comment: I have MouseListener for the trayIcon itself but i dont know how to add one for the balloon message

Comment: Dawnkeeper - I need it for JAVA not C#

Comment: @Yael It is Java, not 'JAVA'.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to capture trayicon.displayMessage() mouse click on the tooltip baloon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8459878/how-to-capture-trayicon-displaymessage-mouse-click-on-the-tooltip-baloon)