# Handling click events of multiple TaskbarIcon ShowBalloonTips

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, notifyicon

I am using the [Hardcoded.Net NotifyIcon](http://www.hardcodet.net/wpf-notifyicon) to have a Taskbar Icon, Taskbar Context Menu and show some (Windows native-looking) notifications from time to time. For my application I need the ability to show different notifications (i.e. BalloonTips) and a different callback in case a BalloonTip is clicked.

It is simple to register the click on the tooltip, as described here: [BalloonTip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3181594/handling-a-click-over-a-balloon-tip-displayed-with-trayicons-showballoontip). Unfortunately, I have no idea **how to register different callbacks for different balloons** as in the click-event I don't know what exact BallonTip was clicked.